# is it ok to store quinoa, rice, lentils, barley, farro, kasha, black beans in the fridge?

Tags: storage

Is it ok to store beans, rice, grains in fridge? I've been doing this method for years....lots of rotation as I use these regularly. Is there any nutritional loss?

Comment: Welcome to the site @hannah, questions about nutrition are considered off-topic on this site and this question is likely to be closed as a result. Is nutrition your only concern or do you have other considerations?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the space there's no reason not to, and some good reasons to.
For one thing, it reduces odds of various bugs infesting (or hatching out if the eggs are already present.) For things like ground whole grains (whole wheat flour) it also slows rancidity - though that should not be a problem for the whole grain.

Personally, I'd need a walk in fridge (which I'd love to have anyway) to manage to have space to store dry goods in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best to do. Not that it can not be done. A fridge will dehydrate grains & such. Also odors can be present.  We find it best to store rice in 5 kilo glass jars with tight lids. Smaller jars for flour & beans & such. In a cool dark place. Works best. But if in jars with tight lids it may be better as cool & stable temp. On moisture control & odors.